How a car inverter can diffuse 16 A 230 V if the input is a 12 V car battery?
I have found this car inverter
We say that the power is kept between the input and the output of an inverter like in this thread, so if the voltage in the output is higher and stepped up, the current is mandatory less because we keep the power all along...
But in the output side of the car inverter they show me “16 A 230 V” so it's about 3680 watts, but it's written to be only 500 watts in the product sheet?


The AC output connector on the inverter will likely be a commercial product that could be used in home wiring, not something specifically designed for that specific inverter.  Therefore, the connector will be rated for its normal use - in your case, for use on a household 16 Amp circuit.  In this case, the 16 Amp rating does not impy that it will deliver 16 Amps.

Is this question related to the other question you asked:
https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/717236/why-does-a-230v-16a-socket-supply-only-the-needed-current-to-loads

That's the maximum current rating for the connector. It does not represent the maximum current the inverter can supply.
If the datasheet states the inverter is capable of providing 500W, then the maximum output current for the inverter is only ~2.1A.
If your device (e.g. computer, laptop, etc) draws more than this 500W, then you cannot use it with the inverter regardless of what the connector is rated for.

The connector is likely made by a different company for use in many different applications, so the connector company have imprinted their connectors current rating likely for compliance purposes (*). They probably only make them with this high of a rating as it would probably cost them more compared to demand to make connectors rated at different currents.
The company that made the inverter likely selected the connector because it was the cheapest they could get hold of whilst maintaining a suitable rating and mechanical sizing. The inverter capabilities are less than the connector rating, making a suitable part for their design.

(*) Assuming from a reputable source with any sort of actual compliance testing done - I can't speak for the connector in question.

Thanks but what is current rating (for the connector) ?

So, if  then the maximum output current for the inverter is only ~2.1A... Do the computer will charge slowler than in my house socket 230V 16A ?

@JohnMary unless your computer is some monster server, no commercial PC I know of will use 3.6kW. Your inverter can supply 500W of power, as long as your computer uses less than this, it will work correctly. If your computer uses more than 500W, then you cannot use it with this inverter, simples.

ok, but if at home I plug my computer charger into the 16A 230V socket, will it comsumpt all the 16A or will it draw only required current for my 150W charger ? and if yes, why ? how is it done ?

@John Mary See (here)[https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/34746/53368]. A device only draws as much current as it requires for a given voltage. Your 150W charger will draw at most 150W/230V=0.65A - if it drew any more than that, it wouldn't be a 150W charger.

@Tom Carpenter: "... likely for CE marking compliance purposes." — CE marking may be not  "Conformité Européenne", but "China Export" — see The Differences.

@MarianD indeed, there are no guarantees the connector is properly tested.

(@TomCarpenter: at most 150W/230V=0.65A @η=cosφ=1…)

@greybeard Indeed, but I think bringing up power factor at this point is probably just going to cause added confusion.
