Why does a 230V 16A socket supply only the needed current to loads?

If I connect a 150W laptop charger to a socket that supplies at home 16A 230V, it will only draw the necessary amperage needed for the laptop charger at 230V. Why?
Why doesn't my charger simply draws all the 16A but less than 1 A? (about 0,65 A)
Is there a limiter on my electricity supplier or is it law of electricity?

Is it the same in an electronic assembly with an Arduino or other? To choose the correct resistor for my loads in my circuit I learned that I have to use the battery voltage (for example a 9V battery), the load voltage (eg. 2 V for an LED) and the load maximum current (eg. 20 mA for the same LED) in my calculation, but why don't I need the battery current that is supplied?



The picture comes from here : https://www.circuitspecialists.com/blog/5-steps-to-calculate-the-resistor-value-for-leds/

Non, I don't understand the why...

Bear in mind that an LED is not a normal load. The majority of loads are voltage-driven, while an LED is better considered as current-driven.


If I connect a 150W laptop charger to a socket that supplies at home 16A 230V, it will only draw the necessary amperage needed for the laptop charger at 230V. Why?

The definition of electrical power is:
$$
P = V .  I
$$
The electrical power to your home has a pre-defined voltage.  Likewise, a 9V battery you buy from the shop also has a pre-defined voltage.  You can say these are "constant voltage sources", because the voltage is constant, while the current they can supply is highly variable.
To consume electrical power, a load has to draw current from that voltage.  So the load determines how much current it will draw from the voltage source.
The constant voltage supply to your home may be capable of delivering anywhere from 0 Amps up to 10,000 Amps of current.  It does not care how much current it delivers, its job is to keep the voltage to your home constant.
So, each load connected to the 230V supply will draw the current it requires to supply the power it needs.  However, there is a limit to how much current can be safely carried to your load; this limit is there to stop cables in your home from getting too hot and starting a fire.  So fuses and circuit breakers are installed, these disconnect the voltage source if the current gets too large.
So, to summarise:
Voltage is kept constant.  Current varies dramatically in order to supply the power needed by the load.


Is it the same in an electronic assembly with an Arduino or other? To choose the correct resistor for my loads in my circuit I learned that I have to use the battery voltage (for example a 9V battery), the load voltage (eg. 2 V for an LED) and the load maximum current (eg. 20 mA for the same LED) in my calculation, but why don't I need the battery current that is supplied?


The constants in this equation are the battery voltage (9V), and the LED forward voltage (2V).  The variable is how much current you want to flow in the LED.  Let's choose this to be 2mA.  So the resistor has to be 3.5kΩ.
The (non-rechargeable) battery has to be capable of supplying this current while keeping its voltage relatively constant at 9V.  The maker of the battery will publish a datasheet, this datasheet should tell you how long the battery can supply a given load current before it is considered to be "flat" or "discharged".  A typical non-rechargeable 9V alkaline battery may be able to supply 2mA of current for a duration of about 275 hours (about 11.5 days).  This is given by the graph of voltage vs time for a given constant discharge current, we shall consider the battery being "flat" when its voltage falls to 7.0V; refer image below:

If the discharge current is increased, say to 100mA, the battery is "flat" (its voltage reaches 7.0V) in just 3 hours:

Link for images above:
https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1842389.pdf

Your socket rated at 16A does not know how many hundred or thousand amps are available from your electricity provider and it also does not know how much your laptop needs for charging. If you connect a 60W bulb the bulb will draw 60W. The socket is just rated for safely providing up to 16A into a load so that's why it needs a wiring back to electrical panel that can safely pass 16A and it needs a 16A breaker so in the event of short circuit or someone putting e.g. two 16A loads with a power strip it will break due to overcurrent.

ok thanks, but for your sentence "If you connect a 60W bulb the bulb will draw 60W." ... Why this ? Why does it limit  to the needed current for the plugged  load ... ?

John, if you connect your garden hose to the town supply and open the tap, how come the reservoir isn't drained immediately? Answer: hose resistance to flow. Bigger hose has lower resistance so flow will increase.

@Transistor so, it's due to the resistors inside my plugged load (eg. bulbs... or eg. my laptop charger) ?

@JohnMary Resistors and other things.  With AC, capacitors and inductors act to limit current as well. Mostly with DC (but sometimes with AC too), (certain types of) semiconductor devices do.

Not quite. Some devices such as heaters are purely resistors. (Thin wire -> reduced current. Thick wire -> high current.) Other devices such as motors, solenoids and transformers have "inductance" due to windings. These will also oppose changes in current - important for AC which is alternating all the time.


"Why this ? Why does it limit to the needed current for the plugged load"
For a lightbulb? It's designed that way. A lightbulb manufacturer alters the physical attributes of the lightbulb (filament material, length, cross-sectional area, etc) in such a way that when the "flood gates of current are opened (metaphorically)", the current that goes through is the maximal current that can go through it.


@JohnMary A 60W bulb is a load that takes 60W with the 230V given to it. It can't take more or less. Which means if you have 10 bulbs they take 60W each for a total of 600W, as all of them have the same 230V over each individual bulb. The problem is when you add enough bulbs so that you reach 16A, the socket, or the wiring, or the fuse (circuit breaker) or the supply is not rated to work over that limit. And you have only a 500W inverter so you can't run ten 60W bulbs but maybe eight 60W bulbs.

For a more complex load - a TV set or a computer etc - the self-limiting of current/power is also something that is designed, but obviously not so directly as with a light bulb.

The power consumption is an inherent property of the load as it does what it is supposed to do. Some things takes more power to do than others. Creating heat takes a lot of power, incandescent light bulbs as well (after all, they are heaters first and foremost). When we design circuitry we directly and indirectly control the parameters of the load in such a way that when a voltage is presented to it, the power consumption is a direct consequence.
